# ROS2 topic list only working once (or any other command)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently using a Turtlebot3, completely set up following this guide: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_setup/

Running: ubuntu-18.04.3-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
With ROS2 Dashing installed.

On my REMOTE PC (desktop), I am running Ubuntu 18.04, also with ROS2 Dashing installed.

Also installed following the online guide: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/

**The question:**

When I ssh into the Turtlebot3 and run the following command:

> ros2 launch turtlebot3_bringup robot.launch.py

and then run on the REMOTE PC (desktop):

> ros2 topic list

I get a correct result, showing the available topics that are being published.

However, when I run this command a second time, it only shows the default topics:

> /parameter_events

> /rosout

Any consecutive command after the first one will give this default result. This is also the case if the first time I try the command:

> ros2 node list

or any other ROS2 command. However, **when I kill the '_ros2_daemon', and then run the ros2 topic list (or node list) command again, it works again, but only for that one time again. Leaving me to kill the daemon constantly.**

Can someone help me figure this out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354512/ros2-topic-list-only-working-once-(or-any-other-command)/) by [StanSwanborn](https://answers.ros.org/users/50965/stanswanborn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-06-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chopin1998@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/57192/chopin1998@gmail.com/) on 2020-07-31**:
i have same problme recently..

both on ROS2 version: dashing and foxy

what's wrong?

**Comment by [emvee](https://answers.ros.org/users/66671/emvee/) on 2020-12-29**:
same problem with ros2 foxy, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had same problem before.
When this problem occur, you should restart ros2 daemon with following commands.
$ ros2 daemon stop
$ ros2 daemon start
After that you can get a correct result on "ros2 topic list command".

---

Originally posted by [saitoros](https://answers.ros.org/users/70600/saitoros/) with karma: 56 on 2021-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4